# Inject Code into an iFrame to Hide a Specific Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am attempting to hide an element loaded in an iFrame using CSS/jQuery/Javascript. The iFrame content is located on a different domain. I am trying to hide a button on the page loaded inside the iFrame. The buttons HTML is:

```
<a href="/Communication" id="lbtnMessage" class="bsrpBlueButtonLink">
    <div class="NavButtonMess">
        <span>Messages</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

I have read mixed answers around the Internet on whether or not this is possible. I just need to be able to hide this block of code in the iFrame source. I this at all possible?

Comment: **Not possible.** You cannot hide elements without changing the code on the other domain.

Comment: @ComFreek is it possible to change the code on the other domain using CSS/jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: No, that is not possible. You cannot even access the document object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use postMessage, obviously **you need to control both domains**.

This jquery plugin handles it pretty well : http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

If you **don't** control both domains then, due to security this is impossible. All you can do, is resizing / hiding the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I do not control both domains. Is there a plugin that works without having control of both domains?

Comment: Sorry but due to security this is impossible. All you can do, is resizing / hiding the iframe.